# Adding images and text to an old Excel game

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to update an old VBA Excel application with new images.  The application can be found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/shag/.

I figured out how to update the images: by tediously selecting each of the 64 images and selecting 'change picture' in the Game sheet.  But when I change the name in the Data sheet and then click on that name in the Match sheet I get an error saying that "the item with the specified name wasn't found".

Any idea how I might quickly and easily change all the images and names in the game and have a fully working game at the end?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the shapes on the Game worksheet have names that should match the new names you use

example:
`worksheets("game").shapes(66).name` is `Catherine Zeta Jones`

The first person is shapes(3), the last is shapes(66): also remember that you will have to change the name to match the corresponding picture